# How to get and change the values of the projector lens system?

Tags: hardware-interface, dm-script

I am trying to write a Gatan DigitalMicrograph script to control the tilting of incident electron beam before and after a specimen. I think that the values of pre-specimen lens system can be got and changed by using commands such as EMGetBeamTilt, EMSetBeamTilt and EMChangeBeamTilt. However, I don't know how to get or control the status of the post-specimen lens system such as a projector lens. What command or code should be written in order to control the projector lens system?

It will be appreciated if you share some wisdom. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, only a limited number of microscope hardware components can be accessed by DM-script via a generalized interface. The generalized commands communicate to the microscope via a software interface which is implemented by the microscope vendor, so that the exact behaviour of each command (i.e. which lenses are driven when a value is changed) lies completely within the control of the microscope software and not DM. Commands to access specific lenses or microscope-specific controls are most often not available.

All available commands, while they can be found in earlier versions often as well, are officially supported and documented since GMS 2.3. You will find the *complete* list of commands in the F1 help-documentation (on online-systems):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. I have checked the help documentation on our GMS2.3 online-system connected with JEOL JEM-2100 microscope. Unfortunately, I could not find commands for controlling the projector lens. However, when the version of our system was GMS1.7, I could get and control the status of the projector lens by the commands such as GetPLA and SetPLA. Thus I think fundamentally we can access the parameters of JEM-2100 by DM. Was such kind of commands deleted since GMS2.3? Or, are the commands specialized commands included in any optional plug-in for JEOL microscopes?

Comment: @kachigusa 
 
 
There have been some microscope-specific commands in the past (not documented, not officially supported) which will work for very specific installations only and are generally not 'save'. If you know of any, and they still work for you, you can use them, but there is no support or compatibility-guarantee whatsoever. Different microscope vendors are differntly 'open' with respect of allowing DM to control.

Comment: @kachigusa I have just noticed that one set of projector-commands has been added rather recently and might not be in the documenation of your version yet:  `EMGetProjectorShift()` and `EMSetProjectorShift()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful and kind advices. I could control the projector lens by using EMGetProjectorShift and EMSetProjectorShift.