# DM-script command for projector shift

Tags: dm-script

What is the dm-script command for projector alignment shift (on JEOL)? Or the "diffraction adjust" (on FEI)? I want to shift the diffraction pattern through command. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this thread, [How to get and change the values of the projector lens system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403855/how-to-get-and-change-the-values-of-the-projector-lens-system?rq=1), the answer to my question is in the comment by BmyGuest. 
Just tested out on GMS 2.3. These commands work:

```
void EMGetProjectorShift(number x, number y)
void EMSetProjectorShift(number x, number y)
```

They are the commands I was looking for.